# reverse iterate table (vue)

Tags: html, vue.js

im a bit new to all this but ive been trying to use the slice().reverse() in vue with no luck in the ways ive been attempting. Im trying to reverse the order of this table.

```
                <div v-if="page == 'Calls'" >
                <h2 class="page-title">CALL MONITOR</h2>
                <h4 v-if="Object.keys(calls).length == 0" style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 20px;">No incoming calls.</h4>
                <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; max-height: 90%; overflow-y: auto; margin-top: 20px;" v-if="Object.keys(calls).length > 0">
                    <table style="margin: 0 auto; width: 95%;">
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Caller</th>
                            <th>Details</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>No. Attached</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr v-for="(call, index) in calls" :key="index">
                            <td>{{index}}</td>
                            <td>{{call.source}}</td>
                            <td class="ellipsis"><span>{{call.details}}</span></td>
                            <td>{{call.time}}</td>
                            <td>{{call.location}}</td>
                            <td>{{attached(index)}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <i style="font-size: 1.5em;" class="fas fa-link" v-bind:class="getClass('clickable2')" v-if="current_call.id == null" v-on:click="AttachToCall(index)"></i>
                                <i style="font-size: 1.5em;" class="fas fa-unlink" v-bind:class="getClass('clickable2')" v-if="current_call.id == call.id" v-on:click="DetachFromCall(index)"></i>
                                <i style="font-size: 1.5em;" class="fas fa-map-marker-alt" v-bind:class="getClass('clickable2')" v-on:click="SetCallWaypoint(index)"></i>
                                <i style="font-size: 1.5em;" class="fas fa-info-circle" v-bind:class="getClass('clickable2')" v-on:click="ShowCallDetails(index)"></i>
                                <i style="font-size: 1.5em;" class="fas fa-edit" v-bind:class="getClass('clickable2')" v-if="current_call.id == call.id" v-on:click="EditCall(index)"></i>
                                <i style="font-size: 1.5em;" class="fas fa-trash" v-bind:class="getClass('clickable2')" v-on:click="DeleteCall(index)"></i>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: Show where you do  slice().reverse()

Comment: I was doing it here

<tr v-for="(call, index) in calls.slice().reverse()" :key="index">

Comment: You have Object.keys(calls) which means what calls is an object, below few rows calls is treat like an array: v-for="(call, index) in calls". So which type is actually calls?

Comment: I believe it is an object

Comment: Show me structure of calls